# how to display grep pattern in perl on windows

Tags: perl, grep

How to grep pattern matched lines in perl

for example **sample.csv**

```
Name: john
location: paris
```

In Unix I am able to grep like this

```
cat sample.csv | grep Name | cut -f 2 -d " "
```

but I need it in Windows

Output:

```
john,paris
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `... | cut -f 2,4 -d " "` to get that output?

Comment: What has this got to do with Perl?

Comment: @Mark Setchell - Perl can emulate common Unix tasks on non-Unix platforms pretty easily.

Comment: @mob: Thank you, I am aware of that. But my point was that Perl isn't naturally occurring on Windows, so presumably it has to be installed, so why not just install grep and use a tool the OP is familiar with?

Answer (score 0):

Your example `sample.csv` doesn't actually appear to be a real csv file, which somewhat limits our parsing options.

Therefore, going with a straight regex solution, this might help you some:

```
perl -nle "/^Name: (.*?) location: (.*?)/ && print qq{$1, $2\n};" sample.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
perl -F'\s' -naE '/^Name:/&& say qq($F[1],$F[3])'  yourfile
```

but it makes some assumptions that may not be correct - like if your name or location contain a space. You may need to change single quotes to double quotes on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

For Example, 
my $status="
Name: John \n
Location: Paris\n
Department: Telephone\n";

If we searching for Name mean, the command should return like below from variable

Name: John